# Visual Studio 10 file extensions

Tags: visual-studio

I'm relatively new at MS Visual Studio 2010.  What is the role for the file names .cs and .resx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[.cs files are specified as c# source code files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228500%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  In general, these contain the logic that your application performs, and are compiled byu the C# compiler, csc.exe.  If your project were a Visual Basic.NET project, you would have .vb files instead, containing VB code.

[.resx files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) contain information about resources used in your project, such as mported images, etc.

Comment: I know this was a very basic question but terminology is everything in learning.

Comment: Also, check out http://www.fileinfo.com/software/microsoft/visual_studio if you want to see a page with most, if not all, Visual Studio 2010 file types.

Answer (score 1):

The .cs holds C# source code

The [.resx resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) format consists of XML entries, which specify objects and strings inside XML tags